# Insufficient privileges on an update join

Tags: oracle, join, permissions, sql-update

Scenario:  We generate records for requests to be approved by a manager.  While pending, the manager changes (updated overnight from HR feeds).  We need to update the requests to indicate the new manager.

Here's an abbreviated version of the query that <strike>would</strike> should do that:

```
update (select grw.approver_user_id, gup.supervisor_id
        from   gs3.user_role gur
          join gsu.user_profile gup
            on gur.user_id = gup.user_id
          join gs3.request_workflow grw
            on gur.user_role_id = grw.user_role_id
           and gup.supervisor_id != grw.approver_user_id  -- records with new mgr
        where  grw.auth_status_cd = 'SUBMITTED')  -- reapprovals currently open
set    grw.approver_id = gup.supervisor_id;
```

The problem:  the account executing this query only has read privileges on `gsu.user_profile`.

The inner select works fine and returns all the rows I need to update... but even though I'm not updating `gup.supervisor_id`, it seems I'm required to have write access to that table.  If I execute this as a user that does have write access to `gsu.user_profile`, the update is successful.

Is there a logical reason for this?  I would rather not grant permissions to an account that it does not need.

Thanks!

**Update**

Accepting Thomas' answer... though it doesn't really answer my question of why the account executing an update join would need update privileges to a table it's not updating, I can see the logic in saying "Don't use update joins, they're not ISO standard".

It's a shame, because the difference between what I have and Thomas's suggestion is that there aren't any nested selects in mine.  If anyone knows an ISO standard way of doing a query like this without nested selects, I'd love to know!

Thanks, Thomas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the ISO approved format for an Update statement and see if that works. ISO does not provide for using a Join directly in an Update statement. Rather, you can only use joins via subqueries.

In addition, this may illustrate some problems in your original Update statement if, for example, the subquery used to set `approver_id` returns more than one row which will obviously cause an exception and you'll need to determine how to find the one and only one supervisor_id that should be set for each row.

```
Update gs3.request_workflow
Set approver_id =   (
                    Select gup.supervisor_id
                    From gs3.user_role As gur
                        Join gsu.user_profile As gup
                            On gur.user_id = gup.user_id
                    Where gup.user_role_id = gs3.request_workflow.user_role_id
                        And gup.supervisor_id != grw.approver_user_id
                    )
Where auth_status_cd = 'SUBMITTED'                          
    And Exists  (
                Select 1
                From gs3.user_role As gur
                    Join gsu.user_profile As gup
                        On gur.user_id = gup.user_id
                Where gup.user_role_id = gs3.request_workflow.user_role_id
                    And gup.supervisor_id != grw.approver_user_id
                )
```

Comment: So the ability to do an update on a select like that is Oracle-specific?

Comment: @James B - The ability to bake a join into an Update statement is vendor specific although there is some similarities amongst vendors. Microsoft for example allows for a From clause where you can put Joins. MySQL puts the joins directly in the Update clause which I think Oracle also does. They all have their nuances. However, all of the vendors support the ISO format which is why I suggested it and it makes it clearer where there might be problems.

Comment: Also wanted to ask, why do you say the subquery used to set approver_id returns more than one row and will cause an exception?  The query I've written will execute fine if I run it under another account, and updates 290 rows correctly.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @James B - In your original query, if the joins ended up producing multiple `gs3.request_workflow` rows, you will likely get unexpected results as the same rows would be updated multiple times which is why ISO does not provide for a join directly in an Update statement. In my solution, if the subquery used to set `approver_id` returned more than one row for a given row in `gs3.request_workflow`, it would throw an exception.

Comment: I will get multiple `gs3.request_workflow` records back, but I'm updating the `gs3.request_workflow` records themselves; so far as I can tell, I'm only updating each `request_workflow` record once... but maybe there's something I'm missing.  You're correct that the query isn't designed to handle more than one row, because I would be updating all of the `request_workflow` records with the same supervisor, but I don't see how I'll get an exception... just a mess to clean up : )  But for the data I'm working with, there's only going to be one row returned, so I didn't worry about it : )

Comment: Any ideas what the performance impact would be with multiple, nested selects in the update?  That was my primary motivation for using the update join.

Comment: @James B - That's not easy to answer. It would depend greatly on the nature of the data. Only performance tests would be able to make that determination.

Comment: @JamesB - RE: Joins in Update statement - In *my* example, you would get an exception. In the scenario where you use a vendor-specific join in the Update statement, it might quietly execute if if the a given row was technically updated twice (because the join resulted in multiple rows in the table being updated). That's the problem really. If the join resulted in the same row being updated twice with two different values, it wouldn't be obvious why it got the value it did.